# possessive form with plural subjects

Tags: plural-forms, possessives

Larry and Tom own a hardware store.  To me there are two possible ways to use the possessive form:

> Larry and Tom's hardware store.

or

> Larry's and Tom's hardware store.

The first speaks and reads better - and I think is correct due to elision. (?)

Is the second grammatically correct ?  It just sounds too clunky to me.

I'm a native speaker and write a lot, but this one's bugged me for years. It's probably a dupe question (sorry), but I can't find the answer here or in style books.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup. *Larry and Tom* is a conjunct noun phrase, which *makes Larry and Tom’s* grammatically proper; and if the store belongs to Larry and Tom jointly it cannot be regarded as belonging entirely to either separately, which makes *Larry and Tom’s*  semantically (and probably legally) proper as well.

The only problem is typographical: the *’s* looks like it’s attached only to *Tom*. Think of it as *Larry-and-Tom’s* and it won’t bother you any more.

Comment: " Think of it as Larry-and-Tom’s and it won’t bother you any more. "  Ahh +2 StoneyB, I'd award you a *Bothers-Remover* badge had we one to give !

Comment: Or for you IT people, "(Larry and Tom)'s". :-)

Answer (score 0):

These sentences mean different things:

If Larry and Tom jointly own a hardware store then it's the first.

If Larry owns a hardware store and Tom also owns a hardware store, then its the second.

Comment: If it were talking about two hardware stores, would the **store** need to be plural **stores**?