# Possessive Case with a Name and a Pronoun

Tags: sentence-construction, possessives, compound-subjects

How do I change, for example, *"the party/wedding/relationship/... of John and I"* into **the possessive case** (possessive using 's)?

My train of thought goes a little something like this:

> The party/wedding/relationship/... of John and I
>
> (John and I)'s party/wedding/relationship/...
>
> (John)'s and (I)'s party/wedding/relationship/...
>
> John's and my party/wedding/relationship/...

Is this correct? **I feel like it's similar to the distributive property in math**. When using the possessive to denote a shared possession between two or more people, **do you use the possessive case ('s) after the name and a possessive adjective in place of the subject pronoun?** Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance!

Edit: Hi. It's been a month. Yes, my thinking is correct. It is also correct if there are two names involved ("John's and Jane's relationship/friendship/etc.). All I ever wanted was a definitive yes or no answer, but they just deflected. Hope this helped someone. No one was ever helpful on here. In fact, I shouldn't even be here. I'm a native speaker, ffs, but for some reason my question about a legitimate usage of English Grammar was so unimportant and unacademic that they "suggested" <s>(closed my question and moved it)</s> that I would be more suitable here. Thank you all so much, you really have proved your deuterostome traits by not ever evolving beyond that stage.

Love, me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [possessive form with plural subjects](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10193/possessive-form-with-plural-subjects)

Comment: @ColleenV no. The example you gave me was of possessives with two proper nouns (names). My question is about a name and a personal pronoun.

Comment: Perhaps just one noun at a time would be easier to understand. If you read what this professor thinks, just avoid this situation and say: Our relationship, party or wedding. https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/19/joint-possessives/ [I know how you feel. :)]

Answer (score 1):

In traditional grammar rules, "of John and I" would be an error, as "John and I" is the object of the preposition "of" and so should be in the objective form: "of John and me".

The English "apostrophe s" derives from the Old English genitive case, but it nowadays functions as a clitic (a little word, written as a suffix).  It is usually added to the end of phrase to give:

> It is John and Sally's party.

It is problematic when the second noun is a pronoun.  The usual solution is either to reverse the order, and use "mine":

> It's mine and John's party.

or completely rephrase

> It's my party that I'm sharing with John.

With "wedding", you would normally use a pronoun (since the identity of John is probably clear from context.

> Our wedding

With "relationship" there are lots of options.

> My relationship with John

> the relationship between John and me

The key take-away is that 1. Yes this is problematic, but 2. Solve the problem, don't get stuck on using a particular form of grammar.

Comment: But is my thinking correct, though? Would saying "Sally is attending John's and my party" be grammatical?